# Crate/PDO Usage Examples

Tags: php, pdo, crate

Has anyone successfully installed Crate/PDO.

I seem to be banging my head against this one.

I have used composer to create the json file and when i try to

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

try {
  $dbh = new PDO('crate:localhost:4200');
  foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from testtable') as $row) {
      print_r($row);
  }
  $dbh = null;
} 

catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}

?>
```

It comes up with error Could not find driver.

Any help or installation documents would be great. anyone got any example code working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crate PDO adapter is not official supported and included by PHP PDO, so the Crate PDO class must be used instead of the standard PDO class.

You should either import the Crate\PDO\PDO class by `use Crate\PDO\PDO;`

or use a full qualified classname:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

try {
  $dbh = new \Crate\PDO\PDO('crate:localhost:4200', null, null, []);
  foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from testtable') as $row) {
      print_r($row);
  }
  $dbh = null;
}
```

Comment: unforunately i am getting

Fatal error: Class 'Crate\PDO\PDO' not found in /var/www/html/index.php on line

Comment: No worries. you led me down the right path. Composer wasnt working correctly. Now its pulling in the correct dependancies it is working. Nice Work.

Comment: @Graham, could you share what you did to fix the Class not found problem? I'm running into the same thing. I don't have much experience with composer yet, but it looks like it downloaded lots of stuff to the vendor dir, although I don't see any files or dirs called crate...

Comment: @michael, i was pulling my vendor files into a different folder that u was referencing in my php file. Once I had got the auto load file in the right place it all started working

Answer (score -4):

Just do it this way and you will be okay. Give me a shout if you needs more help.... Sectona

pdo_connect.php

```
<?php




$db = new PDO (
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sectona_db;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username

    'root6a' // password
);

?>






<?php


require("pdo_connect.php");






$result = $db->prepare('SELECT table_data,table_name FROM testable');

        $result->execute(array(
            '
    ));




    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {



$tb1=htmlentities($row['table_data'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$tb2=$pid=htmlentities($row['table_name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

echo $tb1;
echo $tb2;

}


?>
```

Comment: Isn't this using the MySQL driver? Don't I need to use the crate one?

Comment: No as long as you are using Xammp server, PDO is automatically enabled. Just create table, run the code and then get back to me

Comment: @Sectona What are you on? This has nothing to do with mysql nor Xammp!